# Какие технологии использует проект "Легенда наследие драконов" ?

Tags: веб-программирование, разработка-игр

Какие технологии использует проект "Легенда наследие драконов" ?

Comment: @Анатолийй, вряд ли "за что". Скорее надо спросить - "зачем"?

--

@DreamChild, в самом деле, может быть здесь есть люди, которые смогут интересно рассказать сообществу о том, как написана эта браузерная игра, но у них не хватает баллов для переоткрытия вопроса.

--

Пусть повисит. Если никто не знает, то через денек-другой вопрос сам  исчезнет из поля зрения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хедарах написано нгинкс. Язык не указан. Значит единственный шанс - спросить у создателей